# http content got served on https website issue

Tags: node.js, http, https, web-development-server, mixed-content

I converetd http web to https ( https using nodejs ). 
There is a dropdown on website which on select downloads excel files ( from another http ( not https) server. 
Now this still downloads excel files despite being https now.

I'm not using any mixed content plugin or any such or cors.
Please clear my doubts. How http content got served on https ?

Comment: A download is a navigation to a different URL. It’s not an embedded resource, like an image or video or stylesheet or script. Mixed-content restrictions only affect resources that are embedded in document; they don’t affect resources that the document provides a link for downloading — any more than they prevent the document from having an `a` hyperlink with an `href` to some non-https site. Once a user follows such a link, they’ve navigated away from the original document to a completely different document. Similarly, downloads are completely different documents.

Comment: @sideshowbarker its not a direct download link in my case( i forgot to mention ). On click a restAPI call is made to another subdomain( http) which serves the http content. Since click is actived on client side , shouldn't browser prevent call to http link ?

Comment: Regardless of how the download is initiated, the downloaded item isn’t part of the content of the document. So the document doesn’t have any mixed content. The scope of the mixed-content spec is the document, including any resources that get embedded the document — because those are the resources that if served insecurely can compromise the integrity of the document. And the purpose of the mixed-content spec is to prevent the integrity of a document from being compromised. A download from an insecure URL doesn’t affect the integrity of the document from which the download is initiated.